# Using views to generate a summary view of nodes

Tags: views

I have been wrapping my head around this problem. Basically I have changed the post settings to teaser mode. And I have made views that filters node of certain type . To conclude, I want my nodes to be displayed like in this link http://asblab.mie.utoronto.ca/research 
where the research links has a summary view with the read more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a million different ways to do things in Drupal, but:

1. Create a View
2. Filter on node published and type
3. Sort by whatever criteria you desire and select how many items you want displayed
4. In Fields, select:

   a. Node Title - link to node

   b. Body or Field that contains the description you want displayed (select Trimmed if you want it shorter than all of it) and remove the label

   c. Node Link - enter Read More as the text to display and remove the label

and you should be on your way...

Comment: should the row style be fields or nodes, I am actually still a bit confuse about the fields term.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be field style in my example above

Comment: Nodes are made up of individual fields so in field style, you can pick whatever ones you want to display.  If you pick node style, you can pick either page or teaser views of the ENTIRE node.

Comment: ok i will try that now and let you know.

Comment: do i select body inline when selecting fields as row style?

Comment: No, from your example you want each field on top of the next one, not inline or next to it, so none of them should be inline.

Comment: It seems like it works :D. However, I don't like the the format where, it is like "body: {and the description here}." How do I remove the text "body"?

Comment: That's the label information.  You can get rid of it in the configuration of that field.  Some have a label field and others have a widget that you can select 'No Label'  Click on the gear thingy and lots of options will be presented.  Just remove "Body" from there and it will disappear.

Comment: Can I make the title Larger in font? Thanks again for all the help. I am still not sure how to replace view with Read more, as I have removed the label but view continues to stay there.

Comment: Yes, of course you can make the font bigger, but that's CSS's role in all of this...as to your Read More issue, not sure what is going on there.  The steps I've outlined work here so just make sure you are selecting Node: Link and entering the Read More in the text to display area and then also removing any label information from that field.

Comment: I have removed some comments. Please don't use comments for an extended discussion; for that there is the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers).

Comment: Do you mean that I make a CSS role and then implement it in the node.tpl.php file?

Comment: Can you come to chat room?It would be easier, since the admin seems to be deleting our msgs.